# Where can I find a cheap diamond stone-cutting blade for my Dremel Multi-Max?

Tags: flooring, product-recommendation, fireplace, laminate-floor, powertools

I'm getting ready to place laminate flooring in a room with a brick fireplace.  As per Mike's recommendation [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1651/how-should-laminate-flooring-be-secured-next-to-brick/1654#1654), I'd like to use my Dremel Multi-Max tool to cut a space in the base of our brick mantle for the laminate boards to fit under (giving it a cleaner look). .

The only problem now is that the stone-cutting blades I've seen at Home Depot are a bit pricey ($25 - $35 for a single blade).  Is there anywhere I could find the blades for a cheaper price? Are there alternate blades I can use from different manufacturers? Or does it have to be made by Dremel?  I would assume that the connection type is proprietary in design and only dremel blades will fit on dremel tools.

Comment: I noticed the vote to close.  Sorry -- in retrospect, I can see how this question could be a little off-topic.  I'll be more vigilant in the future and appreciate the answer!

Comment: I really hate to sound like the nay-sayer, but gotta warn you. if you got several feet of brick to undercut at least 1/4inch deep, your gonna have a very tough time doing it with a Dremel multimax tool. Have several blades and a lot of time. This tool is designed for light duty cycles and really not powerful enough to cut long runs of brick. Although an angle grinder and a masonary wheel is much dustier, it will do the job quickly and remove all the material at once, in a fraction of the time

Comment: @shirlock Thanks for the heads up. Good to know.  Yea, I have about 8 feet of brick to cut into about 1/4 to 1/2 inch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [online store](http://tps-diamond-tool.amazonwebstore.com/DB1O-VersaTool-DB1O-Electroplated-Diamond-SemiRound/M/B003NABOKO.htm?traffic_src=froogle&utm_medium=CSE&utm_source=froogle) has them for $15.90 each, and claims to be compatible with Dremel Multi-Max.

**EDIT:** Taking shirlock's advice in mind, the right tool for the job can make all the difference. I did a bit of searching, and [DeWalt has an angle grinder for pretty cheap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BM6BMS) - only 4x the cost of the multimax blade! [Ryobi has one](http://www.homedepot.com/Tools-Hardware-Power-Tools-Grinders/h_d1/N-5yc1vZbauqZ608q1/R-100382520/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) for about half that price too.

[Masonry wheels](http://www.buy.com/prod/masonry-depressed-center-grinding-wheel/q/sellerid/21200627/loc/66357/210577806.html) for it are fairly cheap as well. (Although shipping will get you - might want to go to HD or Lowe's for these.)

Comment: Key phrase was: 'dremel multi max compatible diamond blade' via Google Product search

Comment: oOoOh!  I didn't know angle grinders were that inexpensive. NICE!  Thanks.

Comment: There are few situations in which rationalizing reasons to buy new tools isn't the answer. (At least that's what I tell my wife!) :)

Comment: You can buy a very good DeWalt for around $60.00 and wheels are cheap.